# Cannot boot: kernel panic not syncing

Tags: boot, kernel, sync

This is my first time asking questions here. I apologize for my poor English.

I was using Ubuntu 13.10. While unzipping a passcode-locked file, my system crashed. Since then when I try to boot the system, it shows:

```
kernel panic not syncing attempted to kill init! exitcode 0x00000007
```

More letters are shown after that.  I cannot boot any more.

This is the picture of screen:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0vvtD1XMntRbUxTQ0xGRUMwYk0/edit?usp=sharing

Now I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 in another partition and am using the machine.

Specs of laptop are:

- DELL VOSTRO 1220
- Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T6670 @ 2.20GHz × 2
- 64 bit
- 4GB memory

I want to rescue Ubuntu 13.10, or at least rescue my personal data.

I'm pretty much a beginner but I understand a little bit of terminal commands.

I'm not very good with English, so if you can explain with simple words it will help.

Thank you very much.  I really do need help.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a corrupt file system.

- Boot 14.04
- Start terminal
- Run `sudo fsck /dev/sdx` (replace `sdx` with your 13.10 partition)
- `sudo mount /dev/sdx /mnt`
- Browse `/mnt` and copy your files to your 14.04 partition

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that gets this error, I could finally fix it by installing Ubuntu 10.10. I had previously tried Windows 7, 8, Ubuntu 14.04 and Boot-repair iso without luck.

I solved the problem by reading this report: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+question/219002 .

Here is the answer from that report that helped me:

> In this case, you should reinstall Windows from the installation CD first. In the installation process there is the possibility to partition your disk. Delete all partitions and create a new one for Windows, taking about half of the disk space.
>   After Windows has been installed, you can boot from the Ubuntu installation CD and install Ubuntu. The installer will detect the free disk space and offer you the option to install Ubuntu Linux there. When finished you will have a boot prompt asking you which OS to boot.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.